# Two StatefulWidget in Stack, remove widget A, state of B disposed, widget B use state of A?

Tags: flutter, dart

Pls help a flutter beginner

the widgets hierachey:

Stack1(
Stack2([StatefulWidget t1, StatefulWidget t2],
)

It's so wiered that clicked an InkWell to delete t1 from Stack2.
dispose() of state of t2 invoked. t2 with state of t1 left in Stack.
I wonder it's supposed to dispose state of t1?

here's the sample code:

```
class TestViewState extends State<TestView> {

  List<Widget> lists = List<Widget>();
  Test1 t1;
  Test1 t2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    super.initState();
  }
  void init() {
    t1 = Test1(0, 100);
    t2 = Test1(100, 100);

    lists.add(t1);
    lists.add(t2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        return Container(
          width:500,
          height:500,
          child:Stack(
            children: [
              Stack(
                children: lists
              ),
              Positioned(left:0, top:300,child: Row(children: [
                InkWell(child:
                Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  width:50,
                  height:50,

                ),onTap: () {
                  lists.remove(t1);
                  setState(() {
                  });
                },
                ),
              ]))
            ]
          )
        );
      })
    );
  }
}

class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  Test1State state;
  double x,y;
  static int test = 0;
  Test1(this.x, this.y) {
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    state = Test1State();
    return state;
  }

}

class Test1State extends State<Test1> {
  int st;
  @override
  void initState() {
    st = Test1.test;
    Test1.test +=1;
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    print("widget:"+widget.hashCode.toString()+", state:"+this.hashCode.toString()+", test="+st.toString());
    return Positioned(
      left:widget.x,
      top:widget.y,
      child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: st >0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
      child: Text("11111111111", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30))
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Since here two widgets of same type Test1 are given to ‘lists’, flutter is trying to reuse the states in that tree. For every statefulwidget requested, a stateful element is created by flutter. This state will outlive the widget. When you removed the widget from the lists and called setstate, lists contained the second object of Test1(t2), which was the same type as that of the previous widget which was associated with the state of (t1) . The state of the second element (t2) which was there in the first frame build was no longer needed when set state was called hence disposed.

Comment: If you give different types of widgets to lists and try to do the same thing, this may not reproduce..

Comment: First, you should never store a widget in a property. Second, you can help Flutter identifying the correct widget by assigning them a `Key`, such as a `ValueKey` or `ObjectKey`.